# Cordova android splash screen not showing when using url scheme deeplink

Tags: android, cordova, splash-screen, deep-linking, url-scheme

When using a urlscheme/deeplink to launch my app I noticed that the app starts but there is like a 5+ second white screen before the deeplink page just appears.  There is no splash screen.  If the link opened the app and went right to the content in like 1 to 2 seconds I wouldn't mind (as much).  But from a user perspective, a 5+ second white screen can look like the app has hung or there is no action actually going on.

I have seen other posts with users trying to stop/remove the splash screen when using a deep link, but I need to achieve the opposite.  I am also not certain where to address this issue.  As well, is this something I need to add in the code when handling a deep link or is this something that needs to be managed in the manifest?

I don't ever recall seeing this behavior until the most recent upgrade to APK 33. Everything works as expected on iOS.